# Bash script for user input not working properly

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, variables, scripting

I have the following script:

```
if [ "$5" = "BLUE" ] ; then
      LIST OF COMMANDS

elif [ "$5" = "GREEN" ] ; then
        $existing_user=$(COMMANDS THAT GENERATE THE OUTPUT)    <------------------ Is this configured properly? 
        if [ "$existing_user" = "$3" ] ; then
                LIST OF COMMANDS
        elif [ "$existing_user" = "" ] ; then  
                LIST OF COMMANDS
        fi
 fi
```

My script is working, but it skips the `if [ "$existing_user" = "$3" ] ; then` and goes right to the elif part... When I move `$existing_user=$(COMMANDS THAT GENERATE THE OUTPUT)`, outside of the script it is working fine.

As if I did not configure this variable properly inside the second IF statement?

Comment: Run this with `set -x` to see what's going. It's impossible to tell without seeing the actual commands; I don't see something obviously wrong. Maybe the the commands write to stderr instead of stdout and `existing_user` stays empty.

Comment: `$existing_user=$(COMMANDS THAT GENERATE THE OUTPUT)` => `existing_user=$(COMMANDS THAT GENERATE THE OUTPUT)`

Comment: OMG such a dumb mistake, lurker is right I did put $existing_user instead of existing_user and you just saved my day! Thank you very much for the fast reply guys!

Comment: Oh woops! I take my statement from the first comment back!